# symfony: where should I store and how to retrieve a tax rate?

Tags: symfony

Im wondering where should I store and how to retrieve a tax rate that Im going to use in multiple classes. I would like to set this value as a parameter just one time. Is parameters.yml a good place to set it?

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
*/
protected $taxRate;
```

I will have the code above in multiple classes as I said.

Bear in mind that I want to use also the value on templates.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like it belongs to an Entity. You can share this parameter by creating an abstract class and make all the entities that need and have this property to extend form it:

```
abstract class TaxableEntity {

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $taxRate;
}

class Entity extends TaxableEntity {
    //here you have access to taxRate
}
```

This approach has its drawbacks though, which are the usual drawbacks of inheritance. Once you get many consumers of this API (protected) you'll have a very hard time re-factoring, plus you're enforcing all your Taxable entities to have that field mapped into the DB.

Another approach, would be to wrap the concept of a TaxRate into a ValueObject. This way you'd be able to use it more as a regular attribute but with a stronger type:

```
class TaxRate {
    private function __construct($rate) {
        $this->rate = $rate;
    }

    public static function fromFloat($value) {
        if(!is_float($value)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        return self($value);
    }

    public static function fromInteger($value) {
        if(!is_int($value)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        return self((float)$value);
    }            
}
```

Anyway, the "parameters.yml" has nothing to do with your object's properties, but more about your project's property. For instance, the necessary parameters to connect to your DB would be well located in the parameters.yml:

```
database_host: localhost
database_port: 3306
database_user: user
database_password: password
database_name: db_name
```

This way they can be injected/used in your services by means of the DIC.

Comment: thanks, anyway it is said here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html that `parameters.yml` could be also a good place to store global variables that are going to use in multiple templates. In my case I want to use also the tax rate in templates.

Comment: If you want a global variable for your Twig templates, the parameters.yml is in fact a good place to have it. I got confused by the Doctrine annotation in your original question.

Comment: the fact is that I need the variable in both places: server and templates

Comment: Then bear in mind that my answer only applies to re-using that value throughout your entities.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want to set the value at a single point then the easiest solution would be using a trait.
The benefit is that you can use multiple traits which feels like multiple inheritance instead of a big basic class that is unflexible and does not care about the single responsibility principle.

The trait might look like this:

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use Doctrine\ORM;

trait TaxRate {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $taxRate = 'your_default_value';

    // set get methods here
}
```

You can then use it multiple times:

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use Your\Namespace\TaxRate;

class Entity {
    use TaxRate;

    // more methods here
}
```

Adding parameters from parameters.yml to an entity is quite a mess in Symfony. An idea is to use the entity as a service which is not working when using Doctrine's find(). So I don't recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I should consider to define it as a constant: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#constants-vs-configuration-options

Comment: If you define it as a constant then you wouldn't be able to easily change it should the rate change.

Comment: @qooplmao sorry, but I don't understand you. Sorry beause my english.

Comment: For example, in the UK the VAT rate changed from 17.5% to 20% and it could change in the future, obviously. If the rate was defined as a constant in your entities then you would only be able to have one rate or the other. The rate change may not be an issue for you, but then again it might.

Comment: @quooplmao thanks for your comment, I will take it into account.

Comment: I've added an answer that may make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

An option where you could handle varying tax rates for when they are changed would be to store your tax rates in a separate table and reference that from your entities, possibly using a trait for ease of use and DRY code.

I will be using annotations as it seems that's what you are using.

<kbd>AppBundle\Entity\TaxRate</kbd>

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_tax_rate")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\TaxRateRepository")
 */
class TaxRate
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2, column="tax_rate")
     */
    private $rate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", column="active_from")
     */
    private $activeFrom;

    .. getter & setters
}
```

In this you would store the tax rate and the date the rate became/becomes active. If, for example, you knew that in 3 months the rate was going to change you could add that to your database in preparation but it wouldn't take effect until that date. You would also be able to set an entities tax rates from the past or the future, should the need arise.

<kbd>AppBundle\Entity\TaxRateRepository</kbd>

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class TaxRateRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * Get current tax rate if available
     *
     * @return TaxRate
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function getCurrentTaxRateForDate(\DateTime $date)
    {
        return $this->getTaxRateForDate(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * Get tax rate for a specified date if available
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return TaxRate
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function getTaxRateForDate(\DateTime $date)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');

        $rate = $queryBuilder
            ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->lte('r.activeFrom', ':date'))
            ->setParameter('date', $date)
            ->orderBy('r.activeFrom', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        if (null === $rate) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf(
                'No tax rate available for "%s"',
                $date->format('Y-m-d')
            ));
        }

        return $rate;
    }
}
```

This "getTaxRateForDate" method will find all tax rates that became active on or before today and order them by the date they became active, in reverse, then return the first in the list.. so the last tax rate to become active before the given date. The "getCurrentTaxRate" will do the above but automatically set the date to "today".

You can then create a trait that you can drop into any entity that uses a tax rate, with the trait containing the necessary annotations. The association will be unidirectional meaning you would be able to get the tax rate from the order/invoice/etc but not the other way around.

<kbd>AppBundle\Entity\Traits\TaxableTrait</kbd>

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait TaxableTrait
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TaxRate")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tax_rate_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $taxRate;

    .. getters & setters
}
```

Then in each of your entities you can just add the trait which will add the getter, setter and annotation for the field.

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Traits\TaxableTrait;

class Order
{
    use TaxableTrait;

    // the rest of your entity
}
```

To use this you would then do something like..

```
$order = new Order();
// This, as stated in your custom repository, would cause an exception
// to be thrown if no tax rate was available for "now"
$order->setTaxRate($taxRateRepository->getCurrentTaxRate());
.. set the rest of the order details

$order->getTaxRate();            // would get the tax rate object
$order->getTaxRate()->getRate(); // would get the actual rate
{{ order.taxRate.rate }}         // would get the rate in a twig template
```

Answer (score 0):

Create  service that returns taxrate from  database .

For Performance use Doctrine Second Level Cache ( there will be no difference if you access tax one or hundred times - after first time value would be store in SLC - till end of request )